# Xamarin Android getting image data from Gallery

Tags: c#, android, file, xamarin

I am trying select an image from Gallery, which is stored in external. I then catch the data in `OnActivityResult`. I, then, want to get the byte array data of the selected image using these lines.

```
protected override async void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    ...
    var imageSelected = File.ReadAllBytes(data.Data.Path);
    ...
}
```

However, I got this following error: 
`System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/external/images/media/149144".`

`/external/images/media/149144` is the value of `data.Data.Path`. Also, note that I have added `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in my androidmanifest

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can this by done with media picker plugin https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-with-the-media-plugin-for-xamarin/ ?

Comment: @Milen I have not tried that, but based on my code (using native Android approach), can you tell what I did wrong there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying select an image from Gallery, which is stored in external. I then catch the data in OnActivityResult. I, then, want to get the byte array data of the selected image using these lines.

You are getting the `ContentUrl` from `data.Data.Path`, and `File.ReadAllBytes` can't find a file from a `ContentUrl`.

If you want to get the byte data from the result, you can create a `Bitmap` from the `ContentUrl` and convert the `Bitmap` directly to byte array like below:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    try
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(this.ContentResolver, data.Data);
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg,100, stream);
            byte[] array=stream.ToArray();
        }

    }
    catch (Java.IO.IOException e)
    {
           //Exception Handling
    }
}
```